# Check for key-value pair in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the follow array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => bar
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => bar
        )
)
```

and need to know if exists one or more `type` which value is `bar`, without do this:

```
foreach ($arrayOfTypes as $type) {
    if ($type['type'] == 'bar')
    {
        // Stuff here
    }
}
```

*(Only for learning purposes)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php);

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($stuff, function($item){

    return $item['type'] == 'bar';

});

if( count($filteredArray) > 0 ){

    echo 'There was a bar item in array.';

}else{

    echo 'No luck sorry!';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use in_array: http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Combine it with array_map to flatten what you have. Like so:

```
$new_array = array_map( function( $arr ) {
    return $arr['type'];
}, $array );
in_array( 'bar', $new_array );
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly a `foreach` loop or moonwave99's `array-filter` answer is probably going to be your best bet, but if what you're looking is the shortest code possible and creativity that will make most programmers gag, you could try `serialize`-ing the array and using string-searching functions:

```
serialize(array(
        0=>array(
            'type'  => 'foo'
        ),
        1=>array(
            'type'  => 'bar'
        ),
        2=>array(
            'type'  => 'bar'
        )
    ))
```

becomes

```
a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:"type";s:3:"foo";}i:1;a:1:{s:4:"type";s:3:"bar";}i:2;a:1:{s:4:"type";s:3:"bar";}}
```

So you can now run a `strpos()` or `preg_match()` function to find them. So **your whole function would look like**:

```
$exists = strpos('{s:4:"type";s:3:"bar";}',serialize($arrayOfTypes)); //returns number or false
```

It's short, it's snappy, and get's the job done for simple string keypairs.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as moonwave99's solution but slightly more useful as it's in a function that you can feed a key/value pair to as well, so it can be used to search for any key/value combo:

```
function isKVInArray($k, $v, $array) {
    $filtered = array_filter($array, function($item) use($k,$v) {
        return $item[$k] == $v;
    });
    if(count($filtered)>=1) return true;
    else return false;
}

$k = 'live';
$v = 'y';
$my_array = array(
    0=>array(
        'live'=>'n',
        'something_else'=>'a'
    ),
    1=>array(
        'live'=>'y',
        'something_else'=>'b'
    ),
    2=>array(
        'live'=>'n',
        'something_else'=>'c'
    )
);


if(isKVInArray($k, $v, $my_array)) echo "$k=>$v was found in the array.";
else echo 'No luck sorry!';
```

Answer (score 0):

there's another simple way which is useful when you need to count all the different values

```
foreach ($arrayOfTypes as $type) $cnt[$type['type']]++;
```

To get the number of 'bar' (or to get the count of another value):

```
echo($cnt['bar']);
```